# Function extends object with properties of type any vs unknown

Tags: typescript

In the below type definitions why do `P1` and `P2` have different values?

```
type P1 = (() => 22) extends {[k:string]:any} ? 1:2 //`P1 == 1`
type P2 = (() => 22) extends {[k:string]:unknown} ? 1:2 //`P2 == 2`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Breaking Change: `{ [k: string]: unknown }` is no longer a wildcard assignment target](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes/83af27fca396d172b4d895d480b10c3bacf89112#-k-string-unknown--is-no-longer-a-wildcard-assignment-target) for an authoritative answer.

The [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{[k: string]: any}` behaves specially in Typescript: it's a valid assignment target for any object type.  Usually types like `() => 22` are not given [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures), and so it is an error to assign `() => 22` to `{[k: string]: unknown}`.  Only when the property type is `any` do you get the special permissive behavior:

```
let anyRec: { [k: string]: any };
anyRec = () => 22; // okay

let unkRec: { [k: string]: unknown };
unkRec = () => 22; // error
```

So that's why `P1` and `P2` differ.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/DYUwLgBAhgdgngJRAYwFwQN4QNoGt0DOYATgJYwDmAuurHBAL4DcAUHUshALwQAUAlNwB8EAEyimEAPRSIAe1xQ4LFqEgBXGLg7oseQiXLV0m3DDkB3GI1amO3PoK4jxkmRBDFic4iyA)

Comment: in your [link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes/83af27fca396d172b4d895d480b10c3bacf89112#-k-string-unknown--is-no-longer-a-wildcard-assignment-target) it says: "arg would have had the type { [k: string]: unknown }, which anything is assignable to, so the call would have *incorrectly* been allowed". Why was the call *incorrect* in that scenario?

Comment: The relevant change was implemented in [ms/TS#30637](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30637), which made unconstrained generic type parameters default to `unknown` instead of `{}`. It was [this commit](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30637/commits/5dce9909) that says continuing to allow `{[k: string]: unknown}` to be a universal assignment target for all objects would have caused previously caught errors to go uncaught. I don't know if that makes it "incorrect", but it's the closest I can get to an answer to your follow-up question.